# push-buffer is invalid for instance of type GstWebRTCBin

Tags: c++, webrtc, gstreamer

Hi i am trying to push data into a webrtcbin of Gstreamer.
this is my pipeline which works fine with testdata

```
    pipeline = 
        gst_parse_launch("webrtcbin "
        "name=webrtcbin stun-server=stun://stun.l.google.com:19302 "
        "appsrc ! videorate ! "
        "video/x-raw,"
        "width=1280,"
        "height=720,"
        "framerate=15/1 "
        "! videoconvert ! queue max-size-buffers=1 ! "
        "x264enc bitrate=600 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency key-int-max=15 ! "
        "video/x-h264,profile=constrained-baseline ! queue max-size-time=100000000 ! h264parse ! "
        "rtph264pay config-interval=-1 name=payloader ! "
        "application/x-rtp,"
        "media=video,"
        "encoding-name=H264,"
        "payload=96 ! webrtcbin. ", &error);
```

Now i try to push in some camera data
based on my reading of  https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/app/appsrc.html?gi-language=c

```
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    memcpy(gst_Imageptr, msg->data.data(), msg->data.size());
    gst_ImageBuffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped((void*)gst_Imageptr, msg->data.size());
    g_signal_emit_by_name(webrtcbin, "push-buffer", gst_ImageBuffer, &ret);
    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
        /* some error, stop sending data */
        GST_DEBUG ("some error");
    }
```

but I get the error

```
push-buffer' is invalid for instance '0x55bb4cc0f0' of type 'GstWebRTCBin
```

So my question is, is there a different way to push data into a GstWebRTCBin?
the page https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=c#signals only show signals relevant for setting up a connection.

Thanks for any advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found my problem, and as alyways it was very simple but for me hard due to the lack of knowledge in gstreamer

i tried to push the signal against the webrtcbin wbile i should have been pushing against the appsrc. these are different units.

so i gave the appsrc a name:

```
"webrtcbin name=webrtcbin stun-server=stun://stun.l.google.com:19302 "
"appsrc name=CaliCam !"
"video/x-raw, format=BGR, width=640, height=480, framerate=10/1 !"
```

And then stored the bin for reference

`GstElement *appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name( GST_BIN( pipeline), "CaliCam");`

with that i could push the signal

`g_signal_emit_by_name(appsrc, "push-buffer", gst_ImageBuffer, &ret);`

the memory copy workes with both versions. I am not sure yet if allocating the memory beforehand (the way i did it) and securing its existance is less CPU and Memory efficient or not compared to the suggestion of tomaszmi. but that was not the point in the post

Answer (score 0):

You are using `gst_buffer_new_wrapped` which basically does not copy the memory and refers to the memory owned by `gst_Imageptr` instead. Because of that you need to guarantee that:?

1. `gst_Imageptr` points to an allocated memory of at least `msg->data.size()` size
2. the memory pointed by `gst_Imageptr` outlives the `gst_ImageBuffer` object
3. the memory pointed by `gst_Imageptr` is not replaced by a new data while `gst_ImageBuffer` still refers to the previous one

I would propose to give `gst_buffer_new_allocate` + `gst_buffer_fill` a try and check whether your problem disappear or not. So something like the following:

```
GstBuffer* gst_ImageBuffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(nullptr, msg->data.size());
size_t filled_size = gst_buffer_fill(gst_ImageBuffer, 0, msg->data.data(), msg->data.size());
g_signal_emit_by_name(webrtcbin, "push-buffer", gst_ImageBuffer, &ret);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Your version also works when i add the nullprt for the options
`GstBuffer* gst_ImageBuffer = gst_buffer_new_allocate(nullptr, msg->data.size(),nullprt);`
but it does not solve the problem that the signal is not recognized.